# syntax error, unexpected '[' in PHP

Tags: php

I have an error in my production application, where everything works fine locally...

Here is the code:

```
Route::get('/product-HTML/{id}',function($id){
    /*query voor garantie informatie, stock, product omschrijving, ...  */


    $query = "select w.warranties_name as warranty, pi.products_image as image, m.manufacturers_name as supplier, round(d.preu1,2) as price_excl, round((d.preu1 * 1.21),2) as price_incl, 
    d.referentie, d.st_nu as stock, p.products_id, p.manufacturers_id, 
    pd.products_name, pd.products_description as description, pi.products_image as image, pd.products_url, 
    pd.products_warranty, p.products_tax_class_id, p.products_date_added, 
    p.products_bundle, p.sold_in_bundle_only , p.products_model, d.referentie as reference
    from products p 
    left join products_images pi on (pi.products_id = p.products_id) 
    left join products_description pd on (pd.products_id = p.products_id)
    left join artikelen d on (d.nr = '" . $id  . "') 
    left join warranties w on (pd.products_warranty = w.warranties_id)
    left join manufacturers m on ( p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id )
    where  (p.products_id = '" .  $id . "') and (pd.products_id = p.products_id)";
    $product = DB::connection('aios-mysql')->select(DB::RAW($query))[0];

    $stock_description = "";
    $stock_img = "";
    $info = TRUE;
    /*var_dump($product->stock);*/
    if ($product->stock > 1) {

        $stock = "https://www.aios.be/images/stock/1.png";//tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . 'stock/1.png', 'Ruime voorraad', 10, 10);
        if ($info === TRUE)
        $stock_description .= ' Ruime voorraad';
    } elseif($product->stock == 1) {
        $stock_description = "https://www.aios.be/images/stock/2.png";// tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . 'stock/2.png', 'Beperkte voorraad', 10, 10);
        if ($info === TRUE)
        $stock_description .= ' Beperkte voorraad';        
    } else {
        $stock =  "https://www.aios.be/images/stock/3.png";//tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . 'stock/3.png', 'Momenteel niet in voorraad', 10, 10);
        if ($info === TRUE)
        $stock_description .= ' Momenteel niet in voorraad';
    }




    $html = '<div class="productsinfo right" style="">
    <h3 style="font-size:1.6em;"> ' . substr($product->products_name,0,50) . '</h3>
    <img src="https://www.aios.be/pimg/' . $product->image . '" style="max-width:49%;max-height:90%;" />
    <div id="info" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;max-width:49%;">
        <div class="price" style="color:#0099ff;font-weight:bold;font-size:3em;">&euro; ' . $product->price_incl . '</div>
        <div class="price-ex">&euro; ' . $product->price_excl . ' excl BTW</div>
        <ul>
            <li><b>Fabrikant</b> :<span style="width:200px;float:right;">' . $product->supplier . '</span></li>
            <li><b>Model</b> :<span style="width:200px;float:right;">' . $product->reference . '</span></li>
            <li><b>Voorraad</b> :<span style="width:200px;float:right;">' . '<img src="' . $stock .'" />' . $stock_description . '</span></li>
            <li><b>Garantie</b> :<span style="width:200px;float:right;">' . $product->warranty . '</span></li>
        </ul>
        <script>$("#info li:odd").css("background-color", "#fafafa");</script>
    </div>';

    return Response::json(utf8_encode($html));
    /*var_dump($html);
    var_dump($product[0]->warranty);
    return Response::json(utf8_encode($product));*/


});
```

You can view the error here: http://lichtkrant.aios.be/

It all works fine locally (Windows,  PHP: 5.4.28), but in my production (Debian, PHP: 5.3.28-1~dotdeb.02.0), there seems to be a weird error.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: As the answers state, your production environment doesn't have a feature that your dev environment does. I'd look at making your two environments match in version. Ideally you'd upgrade production, but that's rarely feasible. I'd knock your dev system back a version and look at upgrading both when possible.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question? I'm used to c# and i didn't knew why the above wouldn't work...

I hadn't found any info on Array differences in PHP versions online (yes, i searched).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array dereferencing is a PHP 5.4 feature:

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a
>   function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a
>   temporary variable.
>
> As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for more details. You could get the code to work on PHP 5.3 with a temporary variable:

```
$result = DB::connection('aios-mysql')->select(DB::RAW($query));
$product = $result[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

In php 5.3 array dereferencing is not introduced.
So this line causes error:

```
$product = DB::connection('aios-mysql')->select(DB::RAW($query))[0];
```